# Grouping OpenTSDB metrics

Tags: opentsdb

Could someone clarify whether OpenTSDB supports querying of different metrics by a tag?. The reason behind this question is, the device that we manage reports dozens of metrics, and I need to execute multiple queries(on individual metrics) and combine the values to construct a data per device for certain timestamp.

It would be helpful if there is any java client library that provides the feature of combining different metric values by a tag + timestamp.

Comment: You can specify multiple metric sub-queries in a single query call to OpenTSDB. Of course, you'll have to repeat the tags in each sub-query. http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/index.html#sub-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using openTSDB and openTSDB do not support that. My suggestion is use elasticsearch for a replacement of openTSDB.   It may seems a big change but I think it is also a good one. I just did a estimate on both of these two products (plus kariosDB also). And I think es can replace opentsdb in most situation.

One situation openTSDB may be better is if your data really too much to fit in a few hundred machine.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTSDB expression might be useful for you. http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/exp.html. Using this you can query multiple metrics and combine them using an expression. Though OpenTSDB version 2.3.

Another interesting project could be Bosun. Its an alerting system written on top of OpenTSDB Using its expression language you should be able to combine multiple metrics. https://bosun.org/expressions.